# When to use the asynschronus methods with EF Core?

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework-core

Entity Framework Core provides asynchronous extension methods on `IQueryable`.

Such as `SingleAsync`, `SingleOrDefaultAsync`, `FirstAsync`, `FirstOrDefaultAsync`, `ToListAsync`, etc.

When should I use the normal methods and when should I use the asynchronous variants? How do I know?

Should I always use the asynchronous extension methods or only under certain use cases or scenarios?

Comment: Use asynchronous methods when you want to run asynchronously. Not sure your question makes any sense.

Comment: So if have a ASP.NET Core controller that fetch a object from EF Core and output that, should I do that asynchronously or not? Either works.

Comment: If you don't know the answer, then you need to go and read about what `async`/`await` is.

Comment: I know what async/await is, but usually I don't want to await many tasks, and end up just awaiting one asynchronous task and then I don't know if I benefit from anything.

Comment: As with any performance tuning, measure it and pick the one that helps you achieve your goals. For a faster single request, sync may be better, but for more concurrent requests, async may be.

Comment: @bricelam then I would be in the muddy waters of premature optimization.

Answer (score -2):

From [Asynchronous programming with async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/index):

> Asynchrony is essential for activities that are potentially blocking,
>   such as web access. Access to a web resource sometimes is slow or
>   delayed. If such an activity is blocked in a synchronous process, the
>   entire application must wait. In an asynchronous process, the
>   application can continue with other work that doesn't depend on the
>   web resource until the potentially blocking task finishes.

Comment: Yes, I know, I use async extensively when I use `HttpClient`. But this question is regarding EF Core and which scenarios and use cases to use the different varieties of methods offered.

Comment: That's the same. EF makes network call to your SQL server, waits while server executes the query. If you don't want to waste you server resources for stupid waiting - don't wait, use async.

Comment: So I should *always* use the *Async methods? Even then it is "stupidly waiting" since I use the `await` keyword, right?

Comment: "Always" is not 100% true, because you may face scenarios where [sync programming is better than async](https://www.google.ru/search?q=when+synchronous+programming+is+better+than+async), also async programming have [some specific "must know"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx), but *generally* you should choose async if you have no specific reason to use synchronous.